# Memory management good practices under ARC

Tags: ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

My question is more focused on a navigation stack scenario... I have a, let´s say, main view with several table cells. Each of the cells navigates to a new view, by pushing it to the navigation stack, whose view controller stores data and subviews in several `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray`. The common flow for the app is going back and forth from the main view controller to another of the view controllers, a common scenario. I'll appreciate some recommendations regarding memory management operations I'd perform in such scenario, taking into account that I'm under ARC:

a) Which "cleaning" staff should I perform? Is it recommendable to clean the arrays whenever the views disappear, or would it be better to keep them in case the user navigates again to the view?

b) Regarding the views and subviews, should I also "nilify" them when the view disappears? All of them, including those defined in the `nib` file, or only those I create in code?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating and pushing? What is retaining the view controllers (just the nav controller?)? Standard back button?

Comment: I have views in `nib` files, and I do: `MyViewController *myViewController = [[myViewController alloc] init]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];` when tapping a main view's cell

Comment: and I navigate back with the standard back button, yes

Comment: Collections in my view controllers (`NSArray`, `NSMutableArray`, `NSDictionary`...) are all defined as `@property (strong, nonatomic)`

Comment: Better you should define these with **weak** property(@property (weak, nonatomic)), If those are not much used .. sometimes these lead to **Leaks**....

Comment: No, collections used by the view controller should not be weak.

Comment: @KumarKl What happens if those are weak and, for example, I present a new view modally in top of the one having the weak properties?

Answer (score 1):

When popping one of your detail views, good practice is to release the memory. If in your detail view controllers (and only there) you have strong references to the data (your collections) they will be released automatically on pop.

The navigation controller keeps a strong reference to a pushed view controller, and when you pop it, it nils that reference. Since the only object keeping strong references to your collection is the view controller itself, they will also be deallocated when popping.

**However**, if the data in one of your detail view controllers takes time setting up (for example downloading) and the user frequently goes back and forward to that very view, then good practice is to keep it in memory. You achieve this by keeping a strong reference to the detail view controller in your main view controller (the table view controller). Make sure you only create the heavy view controller once and always push the same instance.

If you keep a strong reference to a heavy detail view controller to make the app faster, then you should nil that reference in `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` of your master table view controller. The memory will automatically be reclaimed if the view controller isn't pushed on the stack. (Just make sure to recreate the view controller if the user wants to enter it again).

**Answer to question b** No, generally you don't nilify your references. As stated above, if the controller that owns the arrays is deallocated, it will automatically release any strong properties.

Example of code in your main table view controller if you want to keep heavy view controllers:

```
// MainTableViewController.m

#import "MainTableViewController.h"

@interface MainTableViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *myHeavyViewController;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

- (UIViewController *)myHeavyViewController
{
    //
    // A getter for the strong myHeavyViewController property. Creates the
    // view controller if needed, or returns it if it already exists.
    //
    if (!_myHeavyViewController) {
        self.myHeavyViewController = ... // Create everything needed
    }
    return _myHeavyViewController;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    //
    // Nil property if we get a memory warning
    //
    self.myHeavyViewController = nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath == /* Index path for the heavy view controller */) {

        //
        // self.myHeavyViewController always calls the getter above
        //
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myHeavyViewController animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```